# Why does reflection work when used in a generic method?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, type-erasure

I read that generics in Java are implemented using type erasure.
I wanted to test that and see if I fully understood the concept, but I was surprised and confused to find out that this piece of code worked perfectly:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String []args){
        canAssign3(3,3.2);
    }

    static<T1,T2> boolean canAssign3(T1 from, T2 to){
        Class<?> c1 = from.getClass();
        Class<?> c2 = to.getClass();
        System.out.println(c1.getName());
        System.out.println(c2.getName());
        System.out.println(c2.isAssignableFrom(c1));
        return (c2.isAssignableFrom(c1) );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.Double
false
```

I was expecting `c1`'s class and `c2`'s class to be `Object`, and also `c2.isAssignableFrom(c1)` to be `true`.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Type erasure happens at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

Generic or not, each object has a Class and it's the method on that class you're invoking.

This method would work just as effectively if both parameters were of type `Object`. In fact, making them generic adds no value, because you're not using the generic type.

Comment: Thanks! so are there any situations in which reflection WONT work due to the use of generics?

Comment: Reflection predates generics by a long way. Reflection doesn't use generics and is unaffected it.